# Running an action in time intervals

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, action, scheduled-tasks, timed

I am developing an asp.net mvc application in which deliver some services to my customers. Every customer has a profile and in that profile there's is a field with customer's birthday date. I want my application to automatically be notified about my customer birthday and by ruining some action, sends him/her 'Happy Birthday' Message.

How could it be possible ?

Comment: How do you want to send the message? Email?

Comment: Actually by using some sms center`s API I send the message to customer mobile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you'd have a database scheduled task to scan your users' profiles (users table) for anyone that has a birthday in the day the scanning process is running.

Select the users that match the query and use a custom class/method to send them a birthday message using [.NET mail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.net.mail.aspx) capabilities.

For more ideas, take a look at: [Send emails in background job/scheduled task in asp.net mvc 3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5159761/114029)